# Make button in form bulder to give next record

Tags: sql

Recently I use form builder to create databases.
I want to make button when user click on it give next record and other button gives previous record.

[image]

What i shoud write in trigger.
Notice the  image the bottons (next,prev).

Comment: Really not sure what your actual question is? what you mean by getting next record?

Comment: Record for other order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this, code below can used to iterate (T-SQL):

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @MyField YourFieldDataType;
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    select top 1000 YourField from dbo.table
        where StatusID = 7      

    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @MyField

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    // YOUR ALGORITHM GOES HERE 
      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @MyField 
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

Or you can use `while` statement:

```
select top 1000 TableID
into #ControlTable 
from dbo.table
where StatusID = 7

declare @TableID int

while exists (select * from #ControlTable)
begin

    select @TableID = (select top 1 TableID
                       from #ControlTable
                       order by TableID asc)

    -- Do something with your TableID

    delete #ControlTable
    where TableID = @TableID

end

drop table #ControlTable
```

Comment: This code i shoud put it in trigger when -button-pressed??

Comment: @Sara Since you have chosen only sql tag for question, I have provided it, this code just shows how to iterate through set and do smth. Of course you some "shell" for all that. And be please more specific